When is a bimodule that is projective as a right and as a left module also projective as a bimodule
Are there practical criteria for determining when a bimodule that is projective as a right and as a left module is projective as a bimodule? Some illustrative examples of what goes wrong and what goes right would be appreciated.

The archetypal example is an algebra $A$ as an $A$-$A$-bimodule via left and right multiplication. That's what gives rise to Hochschild (co)homology.

Just to clarify @DaveBenson's point in case it wasn't clear: if we assume the presence of an identity element, $A$ is always projective as a right or left $A$-module, but is only "biprojective" in very special circumstances.
